# Read input from a discord user

Tags: python

I am trying to read the input from a discord bot so my python script can act correspondingly to what the bot types. Let's say it types "hi", I want my script to type back "hello" to the user. The only thing that is preventing me from achieving this is the "how part." Is there a way of reading input from a discord user?

Below is my script that automates commands on this bot

```
import pyautogui
import random
import time


class Dankmemberclass():
    def AutomateMoney(self, Delay):

        self.delay = Delay


        commands = ["pls beg", "pls fish", "pls hunt", "pls pm", "pls hourly", "pls work"]
        while True:
            time.sleep(random.randint(self.delay, 70))

            pyautogui.typewrite(commands[0])
            time.sleep(random.randint(2, 3))
            pyautogui.press("enter")

            time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))

            pyautogui.typewrite(commands[1])
            time.sleep(random.randint(2, 3))
            pyautogui.press("enter")

            time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))

            pyautogui.typewrite(commands[2])
            time.sleep(random.randint(2, 3))
            pyautogui.press("enter")

            time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))

            pyautogui.typewrite(commands[3])
            time.sleep(random.randint(2, 3))
            pyautogui.press("enter")
            pyautogui.typewrite("d")
            pyautogui.press("enter")


commands = ["pls beg", "pls fish", "pls hunt", "pls pm", "pls hourly", "pls work"]
timer = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    timer += 1
    if timer >= 3600:
        pyautogui.typewrite(commands[4])
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 4))
        pyautogui.typewrite(commands[5])
        pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Comment: Try to use selenium which is a web-scraper and it can read any web element, so if you run discord on a browser it can read it.